# Is it possible to send Json Data in the POST request body and an image as form-data

Tags: json, http, form-data

I have a POST request that has an image attached as form-data. I would like to send additional data as json in the request body. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within a single Request call is not possible.
as you can only define one type of body.

One way you can do it is to stringify your json object and sent it as a string params in your form-data